# Objective-C: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() + asynchronous = problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

**Update:** This problem was also reported here, with a more detailed treatment of the cause:

[UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum saves only 5 image out of 10. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097459/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-saves-only-5-image-out-of-10-why)

In my case as well, the error was: "Write busy" - this seems to be an issue related to device speed. There is probably some solution that involves manually handling threading or similar - but, inspired by Tommy's answer below, I serialized the saving of images, and that works around the problem.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Situation:**

I'm trying to save a large-ish collection of images to the camera roll using a for-loop (number of images depends on user input - may be 1, 2, 3, or theoretically hundreds). Images are pointed to by an `NSSet` (though I could just as easily do an `NSArray`), and the `NSSet` is set to `nil` after the for-loop completes.

I'm using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` to save out the images on a detached thread (using `NSThread`'s `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` class method), and starting a `UIActivityIndicator` spinner on the main thread.

**Problem:**

When I attempt to save out more than ~5, any image after the ~5th will output this error in the log:

`*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL`

For example, let's say I exported 9 images. The for-loop will run through all 9 images (confirmed by NSLogging), but I'll get around 4 iterations of the error above (and only 5 images saved to the camera roll).

If I add a breakpoint in the loop and wait a second or two in between each iteration, however, they are all saved correctly without complaint. So..

**Theory:**

Based on my logs and observations, `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` is clearly running asynchronously and is somehow 'too slow' to keep up with my application.

Is there a simple way to force it to run synchronously (ideally on the main thread)? I've been experimenting with adding reference counts to the images I'm trying to save out, but (1) this feels hacky, and (2) I haven't solved the problem regardless.

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Locking the main thread means that your activity indicator will not animate. Your app will appear to hang.

Comment: Yes, `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` runs as asynchronously. The error log sounds like the image you want to save is null, check your image data.

Comment: @danielbeard - yes, correct, sorry - clarified my threading above in the second paragraph of **Situation**

Comment: @fannheyward - I've confirmed that the data is good with breakpoints. If I run as normal with 8 images, 5 will work and 3 will fail. However, if I add a breakpoint at the end of the loop (after `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`), and wait 1-2 seconds before 'continuing' the loop on each cycle, it will correctly export all 8 images without complaint or error.

Comment: If you are on iOS8 or higher, use the the Photos frameworks. It will handle this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're desperate not to write multiple images at once then you could use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`'s completion target and selector to implement a form of tail recursion. Something like:

```
- (void)writeSetToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSMutableSet *)images
{
    if(![images count]) return;

    UIImage *imageToSave = [[[images anyObject] retain] autorelease];
    [images removeObject:imageToSave];
    NSLog(@"I shall now write image %@", imageToSave);

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
            imageToSave,
            self,
            @selector(writeSetToSavedPhotosAlbum:),
            images);
}
```

EDIT: it may also be worth seeing whether you get the same results with `ALAssetsLibrary`'s [`-writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum%3aorientation%3acompletionBlock%3a), which takes a block for completion so is even more straightforward to work with.

Comment: I'll experiment with this a bit, but just to confirm: **I am 100% OK with writing all of the images at once**. Your answer implies that there may be a way to do this? The loop is merely my implementation for passing all images to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`..

Comment: Sorry, I meant not writing multiple images at once in the sense of not allowing `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to parallelise your work even if it wants to. So the tail recursion answer I give forces a serial conversion and write regardless. So it'll be a workaround if there is some sort of problem in Apple's code. There isn't any method I'm aware of to pass a set or array of images directly to the assets library and ask it to write all of those according to such scheduling as it prefers.

Comment: I've used a method similar to yours to resolve the problem more or less (I'll update the question with details). It's now causing havoc with my activity indicator because the mainthread is now 'done' before the actual images are written out, but now we're on to a separate problem that I can tackle.. :)

Answer (score 6):

I use ALAssetsLibrary and a `dispatch_queue` to make sure that images are saved sequentially:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.saveToCameraRoll", NULL);

[images enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage metadata:metaData completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *writeError) {

            if (writeError) {
                // handle the error
            }
            else {
                if (image == [images lastObject]) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // perhaps indicate to the user that save has finished
                    });
                }
            }

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_release(sema);
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs do mention you'll be notified asynchronously. I wonder if this might work: for each image you want to save create a block operation and add it to main operation queue. Kind of like:

```
for (UIImage *toSave in imagesToSave)
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(toSave, target, selector, ctx);
    }];
}
```

Might be worth a shot, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect this was probably not a great idea - but perhaps implementing some concurrent NSOperation subclasses would work well for this task.

Comment: hard to say - it seems that Apple's method (or is it a function in this case?) just has a mind of its own, and unfortunately that mind can only handle a couple requests at once :)  in the next version of my app, i'm going to experiment with this a bit (running serial sets of 2 concurrently - and if that works, try 3 - and if that works, try 4, etc, etc), but i'm at best a few weeks away from that :)  in the mean time, serial, one-at-a-time saving will have to do..

Answer (score 0):

In this Code Work Save image :

```
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self screenshot], nil, nil, nil);

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Photo saved to album" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```