# Waiting for completion handler to complete, before continuing

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have an array of 9 images and I'd like to save them all to the user's camera roll. You can do that with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. I wrote a loop to save each image. The problem with this is that for some reason, it will [only save the first five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097459/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-saves-only-5-image-out-of-10-why). Now, order is important, so if an image fails to save, I want to retry and wait until it succeeds, rather than have some unpredictable race.

So, I implement a completion handler, and thought I could use semaphores like so:

```
func save(){
    for i in (0...(self.imagesArray.count-1)).reversed(){
        print("saving image at index ", i)
        semaphore.wait()

        let image = imagesArray[i]
        self.saveImage(image)

    }
}

func saveImage(_ image: UIImage){
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    //due to some write limit, only 5 images get written at once.
    if let error = error {
        print("trying again")
        self.saveImage(image)
    } else {
        print("successfully saved")
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is it gets blocked out after the first save and semaphore.signal never gets called. I'm thinking my completion handler is supposed to be called on the main thread, but is already being blocked by the semaphore.wait(). Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should try to put your code in Dispatach.global queue it will surely help

Comment: @MikeAlter It did help. It works now but I don't know why, can you help explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you want to avoid waiting on the main thread, risking deadlocking. So, while you can push it off to a global queue, the other approach is to employ one of the many mechanisms for performing a series of asynchronous tasks. Options include asynchronous `Operation` subclass or promises (e.g. [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)).

For example, to wrap the image saving task in an asynchronous [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) and add them to an [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) you could define your image save operation like so:

```
class ImageSaveOperation: AsynchronousOperation {

    let image: UIImage
    let imageCompletionBlock: ((NSError?) -> Void)?

    init(image: UIImage, imageCompletionBlock: ((NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.image = image
        self.imageCompletionBlock = imageCompletionBlock

        super.init()
    }

    override func main() {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        imageCompletionBlock?(error)
        complete()
    }

}
```

Then, assuming that you had an array, `images`, i.e. that was a `[UIImage]`, you could then do:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.name = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".imagesave"
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

let operations = images.map {
    return ImageSaveOperation(image: $0) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
        }
    }
}

let completion = BlockOperation {
    print("all done")
}
operations.forEach { completion.addDependency($0) }

queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completion)
```

You can obviously customize this to add retry logic upon error, but that is likely not needed now because the root of the "too busy" problem was a result of too many concurrent save requests, which we've eliminated. That only leaves errors that are unlikely to solved by retrying, so I probably wouldn't add retry logic. (The errors are more likely to be permissions failures, out of space, etc.) But you can add retry logic if you really want. More likely, if you have an error, you might want to just cancel all of the remaining operations on the queue, like I have above.

Note, the above subclasses `AsynchronousOperation`, which is just an `Operation` subclass for which `isAsynchronous` returns `true`. For example:

```
/// Asynchronous Operation base class
///
/// This class performs all of the necessary KVN of `isFinished` and
/// `isExecuting` for a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass. So, to developer
/// a concurrent NSOperation subclass, you instead subclass this class which:
///
/// - must override `main()` with the tasks that initiate the asynchronous task;
///
/// - must call `completeOperation()` function when the asynchronous task is done;
///
/// - optionally, periodically check `self.cancelled` status, performing any clean-up
///   necessary and then ensuring that `completeOperation()` is called; or
///   override `cancel` method, calling `super.cancel()` and then cleaning-up
///   and ensuring `completeOperation()` is called.

public class AsynchronousOperation : Operation {

    private let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".opsync")

    override public var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }

    private var _executing: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            return syncQueue.sync { _executing }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            syncQueue.sync { _executing = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }

    private var _finished: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            return syncQueue.sync { _finished }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            syncQueue.sync { _finished = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }

    /// Complete the operation
    ///
    /// This will result in the appropriate KVN of isFinished and isExecuting

    public func complete() {
        if isExecuting { isExecuting = false }

        if !isFinished { isFinished = true }
    }

    override public func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true
            return
        }

        isExecuting = true

        main()
    }
}
```

Now, I appreciate operation queues (or promises) is going to seem like overkill for your situation, but it's a useful pattern that you can employ wherever you have a series of asynchronous tasks. For more information on operation queues, feel free to refer to the [Concurrency Programming Guide: Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

Year ago I faced Same problem

You should try to put your code in `Dispatach.global` queue it will surely help

Reason : I really don't know about reason too , I think it what semaphore it is , May be it is required to execute in Background Thread to sync wait and signal

Answer (score 0):

As Mike alter mentioned, using a `Dispatch.global().async` helped solve the problem. The code now looks like this:

```
func save(){
    for i in (0...(self.imagesArray.count-1)).reversed(){
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [unowned self] in
            self.semaphore.wait()

            let image = self.imagesArray[i]
            self.saveImage(image)
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem was that the completion handler gets executed in the main thread, which was already locked by the `semaphore.wait()` called initially. So when the completion occurs, `semaphore.signal()` never gets called.

This is solved by running the tasks an asynchronous queue.